# Adding jQuery plugin

Tags: 7, theming, javascript

I'm trying to use [a jQuery plugin](http://www.jqueryscript.net/chart-graph/jQuery-Plugin-To-Render-A-Bar-Chart-From-A-Table-Table-Barchart.html) on a page to turn a table written in HTML into a bar graph. When I wrote the HTML and tested it from my computer, it works fine, but integrating it into the Drupal page doesn't seem to work.

I have the PHP filter turned on for the website.  My code for calling the file on the server and initializing it ready.

```
<?php
  drupal_add_js('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js', 'external');
  drupal_add_js('Biosci-jembrown.lsu.edu/usr/share/drupal7/aschoo2/TableBarChart.js', 'external');
?>
<link href="Biosci-jembrown.lsu.edu/usr/share/drupal7/aschoo2/TableBarChart.css" rel="stylesheet">
<?php
  drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('#machineHours').tableBarChart('#target', '', false); });', 'inline');
?>
```

When I save from the HTML text format of the page, I get a table; when I save from the PHP text format side, I don't get anything. How can I get the site to read the files and show the graph?

*******Edit:
I added the files through theme.php but it still doesn't work.  Perhaps the problem is the script that sends the names of containers as perimeters?  This is the theme.php where I added the code:

```
function bartik_process_page(&$variables) {
 //other code
drupal_add_js('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js', 'external');
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'bartik') . '/template/TableBarChart.js');
$variables['scripts'] = drupal_get_js();
print $scripts;
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'bartik') . '/template/RunJS.js');
$variables['scripts'] = drupal_get_js();
drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme', 'bartik') . '/css/TableBarChart.css');
print $scripts;
```

Comment: Also the .js file is wrapped in (function ($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.cdgi = {  .................................. }
    }
}(jQuery));

Comment: Why not loading the js and css in hook_preprocess_page()? You can implement the hook function in template.php of your theme.

Comment: I only want it included on one page, not the whole site

Comment: Anyway, adding js in body is not a proper way in Drupal. You can add if statement in hook_preprocess_page() as condition to load js and css in specific page. Please check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066473/add-js-file-on-a-certain-page-on-drupal)

Comment: @Ashley, 2nd JS file and CSS - are these files located in your machine? These URL seems to be incorrect - Page not found, please check console in your browser to make sure these are loading properly in your page and there are no errors. If these are located in your machine then copy them in side Drupal directory and include them the normal way check e.g. [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_add_js/7)

Comment: The files are on a server that has other files for the website.

Comment: @Yogesh, how would I add the files to the Drupal Directory?

Comment: So I added the css and js files to the template.php, and it still doesn't work.  Where do I add the section that tells it what parts of the html to be processed by the js file?